# YAP prolog cpu seconds

Tags: prolog, yap

I'm using time/1 to measure cpu time in YAP prolog and I'm getting for example

514.000 CPU in 0.022 seconds (2336363% CPU)
yes

What I'd like to ask is what is the interpretation of these numbers? Does 514.000 represents CPU secs? What is "0.022 seconds" and the CPU percentage that follows?

Thank you

Comment: This is somehow a bug. Please show the entire transscript including the version number.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Well the actual goal in time/1 calls problog  for probabilistic inference and is quite lengthy,so I don't think it is possible to reproduce here. However the same format appears in simple queries:

Comment: % Restoring file /usr/local/lib/Yap/startup.yss
YAP 6.2.3 (x86_64-linux): Tue Apr 16 22:22:50 EEST 2013
   ?- time(writeln('test')).
test
% 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (Inf% CPU)
yes

Comment: `% Restoring file /usr/local/lib/Yap/startup.yss`  
`YAP 6.2.3 (x86_64-linux): Tue Apr 16 22:22:50 EEST 2013`  
   `?- time(writeln('test')).`  
`test`  
`% 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (Inf% CPU)'  
`yes`

Comment: sorry for multiple posting I'm not quite familiar with formatting options in stackoverflow comments

Comment: That must be an error of the specific version. What do you get for: `time(length(_,10000000)).` ?

Comment: Current version is 6.3.4

Comment: For the length query I get `% 1.940 CPU in 2.041 seconds ( 95% CPU)`

Comment: I installed the current stable version from git and compiled from sources. 6.2.3 is the current stable version if I am not mistaken, 6.3.4 is a development version.

Comment: Are you doing something with threads ; or in parallel ?

Comment: This could be the case. I'll check the code again. Thank you